# Parse and Validate Fullname field?

Tags: validation, parsley.js

Is there a client-side library/plugin, which would validate a Fullname input field (last name required)? I am changing fistName and lastName fields into FullName field.

It should also parse the field into first and last names, e.g:

```
John  - invalid
John Smith - valid
John Smith Jr - valid
John Long Smith Jr - valid
Mr John Long Smith Jr.  ??? what are first and last names?

etc
```

I am using parsley.js, but it doesn't parse full names into the first and last names.

Comment: So basically if there's a space in the string, it's valid?  How are you defining a "Last Name"

Comment: That's exactly my point, that I don't want just to use space-delineation, but hope for the library, which would recognize last names and prefixes, like Jr etc..

Comment: Soooo...  Then if someone has a non-standard name, your system won't let them fill out the form?  How would a library recognize "names".  A name can literally be any string - in any language...

Comment: I am probably looking to identify all the pre/suffixes, because if you enter Mr John Smith Jr, your parser will fail with the space delineation

Comment: Ah, that clarifies things a lot

Comment: Kinda curious why you'd want to make life hard on yourself by converting a standard first name, last name form into a full name field....

Comment: improving our CRO by eliminating additional fields, having one field instead of 2 will have a huge impact, especially on the mobile devices

Comment: Fair enough.  There'll inevitably be edge cases where things will be incorrect.  But I suppose if you're storing the fullName, as well as the first and last, and doing any shipping or whatever using the fullname, as the user entered it, then you should be fine.  If you're relying on firstName and lastName always being correct with a system like this, I think you're in for a world of hurt down the road...

Answer (score 0):

I may just found an answer to my own question:

https://github.com/joshfraser/JavaScript-Name-Parser